# Project Menus: (Changes, Pull Requests, Team Members, Branches, Sync ) not visible in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio IDE no longer shows all the Project Menus?  How to get them back?

[image]

---

I should add that the bottom Right corner shows the repository, branch and number of changes.  So the question is how to display the options in the Project panel.

[image]

Comment: Did you connect to a correct team project in VS?

Comment: added more info

Comment: Check my updated reply below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git features have moved in the latest VS. Tools and commands for Git source control are now in their own tool window "**Git Changes**":

[image]

If you want the Git features show in Team Explorer, you can change this setting in **Tools -- Options -- Preview Features**:

[image]